Please sign in with google. Constant pop up
On many websites that require login, these annoying Google login prompts appear:

How can I block them?

There is not info given here that can be used to offer any help. Please edit the question and add some details.

What more information would be appropriate?

What is this colonist.io site and why does it want you to sign in would be one thing.

Why it wants me to sign in is inconsequential. It's not just the one site, it's reddit, it's stackexchange, it's everywhere. Hence why I assumed it might have something to do with the browser.    https://cdn.imgchest.com/files/d7ogcma8mmy.png

Then your question needs to say that. Please edit the question and add that info.

While it is encouraged for users to answer their own question, Please Edit your question to be a question, then provide a answer. See Can I answer my own question?

I’m voting to close this question because it's not Ubuntu specific, and it has been answered on another SE site.


Add this line to "my filters" in uBlock origin:
accounts.google.com/gsi/*

Click on the three gears in uBlock Origin, then go over to "My Filters" and paste the above line into the page below and then click "Apply Changes".

Answer moved here from @totalconfusion's original question.

These popups are a pest on many sites now. 2 ways I know of to block:

Any adblocker that allows you to dynamically block an element, you can choose that option and then highlight the popup. That is usually enough although you will need to do that on every site the window appears (unless you configure a more generic filter).

or

You could install a script blocker such as NoScript which allows you to enable/disable scripts from domains. So on that site you enable scripts from colonist.io but leave all other (e.g. google) scripts blocked.


Adblocker element blocking doesn't persist through a refresh. Will NoScript break a lot of sites?

Probably you are adding an exact filter, add a more generic filter such as ||accounts.google.com/gsi/iframe/select?client_id= NoScriipt allows you to enable scripts on from the domains you want and use but disable scripts for sites you don't want or need.

NoScript is a Firefox extension right? Can we first 100% rule out this being a browser thing? It's so consistent over so many sites... I'm running Firefox ESR on Debian 12 (bookworm)

@totalconfusion It's not a browser thing. Most websites that can be logged into using Google account display this thing recently.

thanks @raj you're right it's not a browser thing. I killed it with a custom filter in ublock origin
